# System Requirements for a Mac to Develop in MonoTouch and XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, xamarin.ios

I want to develop C# and .NET based iPhone applications in MonoTouch. But my goal is to develop iPhone applications so things may end up with Objective-C -so Xcode- too.

Obviously, I have to buy a Mac. I've been lookin' for sales and found a couple of good machines but I still want to make sure that I can use these 2 programs in good performance.

So I want to know that if anyone uses these programs could advice me some system requirements? For example, does the CPU matters? Should I buy an iMac with Intel CPU our is G4-G5 better? And what about the VGA and RAM? Is 1GB or 2GB enough for ram and 256+ for VGA?

Of course better properties mean better performances but what's the minimum for this? We can talk on iMac.

Comment: You need an Intel processor to do iPhone development - G4 and G5 need not apply. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190662/whats-the-cheapest-mac-development-box-possible

Comment: I actually searched but wrong keywords it seems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [thread](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-September/005023.html) from the monotouch [mailing-list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monotouch). It's about laptop initially but it will give you the specs people are using and recommending.

Answer (score 1):

(It's Mac not MAC).

It'll have to be an Intel one for any iOS development. I'm relatively happy still on a mid 2009 MacBook Pro with 4GB of RAM. To develop with the iOS 5 SDK you'll need at least Snow Leopard - so any Mac capable of running that will be a minimum.

Comment: Thanks. Minimum was not the best word I think, minimum for an average performance sounds better, my mistake.